# Does equicontinuity imply uniform continuity?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

If $\{f_n(x)\}$ is an equicontinuous family of functions, does it follow that each function is uniformly continuous?  I am a bit confused since in the Arzela-Ascoli theorem, equicontinuity is seems to mean "$\delta$ depends neither on $n$ nor $x$."  For example, Wikipedia says:

"The sequence is equicontinuous if, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$|f_n(x)-f_n(y)| < \epsilon$$
whenever $|x − y| < \delta$  for all functions  $f_n$  in the sequence."

but I also seem to recall such a term as "uniform equicontinuity."  Is the definition not universal?

Comment: Can you give your definition of equicontinuity? The one I have, when you have only one element in your family of functions, reduces to the definition of continuity (rather than uniform continuity).

Comment: No. The family of functions $f_n(x) = x^2+n$ are equicontinuous but not uniformly continuous.

Comment: I added the definition from Wikipedia.

Comment: I don't see the above in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity. The article distinguishes uniform and 'at a  point' equicontinuity.

Comment: It was in the Arzela-Ascoli article.  Re-reading the article, I see that it could be taken both ways.

Comment: The underlying space with Arzela Ascoli is compact hence the pointwise- and uniform versions are equivalent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the usual statement of Arzela-Ascoli it does not matter, because you are dealing with a compact metric space, where "uniform equicontinuity" is equivalent to "pointwise equicontinuity". (All the functions have a common modulus of continuity at each point, and so an argument exactly parallel to the proof of Heine-Cantor furnishes a uniform modulus of continuity for all of them.) Since this is the main application of the concept, some authors define the word "equicontinuity" to mean what would be more precisely stated as "uniform equicontinuity". Others prefer the more precise term.

The examples I have in mind are Strichartz and Fitzpatrick. Strichartz uses "uniform equicontinuity" everywhere. Fitzpatrick defines "equicontinuity" in the sense of "pointwise equicontinuity" and then makes the equivalence I mentioned an exercise, rather than dwelling on it in his Arzela-Ascoli proof.

Answer (score 2):

Now it does not. The singleton family $F=\{f\}$, with $f(x)=x^2$ is not uniformly continuous, but it is equicontinuous.

However, if $K$ is a compact metric space and $\mathcal F\subset C(K)$ is an equicontinuous family, then $\mathcal F$ is also *uniformly equicontinuous*.